PhpStorm doesn't show warning when component isn't imported Vue 3
I recently added shadcn/vue to my Vue 3 project (Laravel/InertiaJS).
I've init the project with the shadcn/vue cli
I added a component, the Dropdown, with the CLI.
And now when using the component in my .vue templates, I have no warning for the components that have the same name as the Radix-vue component.
For example, the DropdownMenu component shows me a warning if I don't import it. But the DropdownMenuTrigger doesn't show any warning. And when I hover the mouse on the <DropdownMenuTrigger> it shows me a little popup with "Library: radix-vue@1.9."
But on the browser, it crashes cause the component is not imported.
How could I fix this ?
I tried modifying me tsconfig.js file, my Vite config file, I tried "File -> Invalidate Caches" in PhpStorm. But nothing do.

I feel like it's more of an ESlint issue.

ESlint is disabled on the project, warnings comes from the Vue plugin for PHPStorm I think ? I also tried to install/configure/enable eslint, but that didn't change anything. But before adding shadcn/radix-ui I've never had issues with my deps, or warnings
